# Invalid expression term 'select', 'group' etc

Tags: c#

In the application which I work with I recevie 18 errors like:

```
Error   2   Invalid expression term 'select'    
Error   6   Syntax error, ',' expected
```

Seems that it is connected all together.

Where should I look for the source of problem?

Part of the class with all of these errors:

```
if (this.TicketType == "Delivery")
{
    this.Drivers = new ObservableCollection<User>(this.loginService.GetAllDrivers());
}
else if (this.TicketType == "Drivers")
{
    IEnumerable<User> tickets = 
            from t in this.Tickets                      // here error
            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.DriverName)
            group t by t.DriverName into group           // here error
            select new User()
            {
                Name = group.Key,                      // here error
                Id = (
                    from g in group                      // here error
                    select g.DriverId).First<int>()
            };
    if (tickets == null)
    {
        this.Drivers.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Drivers = new ObservableCollection<User>(tickets);
    }
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Drivers");
}
```

Comment: What are you compiling with? It sounds like it could be a very old C# compiler... or it could be getting confused as you're using `group` as the name of the range variable, which doesn't help. Try changing `group` to `groups`. If you can produce a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem, that would help us to help you.

Comment: I work in Visual Studio 2013, I copied this one problematic class from one project to another and I cannot understand where is the problem...

Comment: `if (tickets == null)` should never be true. If there is no data you will get an empty sequence, not null. You might want to check `!tickets.Any()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: It's strange... (after adding using System.Linq) errors disappeared from the class, but they are still in Error List and I can not build

Comment: Try cleaning the build and then do a rebuild.

Comment: Wherever you have a syntax error, if you try hovering over one of the keywords affected you should get some options in Visual Studio under *Resolve* then you can add additional `usings` which you may be missing.

Comment: I did (clean and build)... but still I couldn't build. Jon Skeet's answer solved the problem.